# How to install previous gcc release in cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, revert

Is it possible to use setup.exe to install a previous gcc release in cygwin?  For example, cygwin ships with gcc4.8, but I need to revert to 4.6 (or 4.5).  Is this possible?

Comment: The better question is, *why* do you "need" 4.5?

Comment: We've got a windows build server that uses cygwin as part of the build process.  The code builds just find on 4.5, but I get gcc errors using anything later than gcc4.6 (4.7 and 4.8 both give compilation errors).  I'm trying to set up a new box as an identical build server, but now that cygwin has upgraded to gcc4.8, I'm unable to get our code to compile on 4.8.  I'm wondering if there is a way to tell cygwin to install gcc4.5 instead of 4.8 during the setup.exe process.

Comment: First, I'd say you should fix your code, or if it truly a GCC bug, report it upstream (unless it's a known issue).  Otherwise, there is the Cygwin Time Machine, but be aware that it is not supported on the Cygwin mailing lists.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the Cygwin Time Machine, I'll check that out.  As a stopgap, I ended up just copying the entire package directory from our current build machine, and using that to set up the new machine.  I agree on fixing the code...in an ideal world, that would happen on demand ;)  Fixing the code is on the dev team's todo list, but as they say "it's complicated".  Right now all I have control over is the build server, and that needed to get working ASAP.